# How to make a triangle shape on active tab

Tags: html, css, tabs, hover, selected

I am creating a dynamic tab with bootstrap where once you click a tab, a thicker black underline will pop up. Like so:

[image: Line]

The code I put in for the black line is:

```
.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a, .nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a:hover {
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

However, I want the black line to have an upside down triangle on the bottom like so:

[image: Line with Triangle]

Is there any way I can create that triangle shape with css and add it to my selected tab? I am not sure how to go about doing this, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try to use it to make triangle shape on active tab

```
 .nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a:after {
content: '';
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 5px solid #000;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
display: block;
margin: auto;
```

}

Comment: This one works. Is there some official documentation on how border width conflicts are resoluted?